# How can I in a DataTable pass the value of a target to a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

For example, in the following code I receive the records from a DB and I need to set the value of the targets: 1 to a variable to print it in other areas of the screen.

```js
tableRefacciones = $('#lstRefacciones').DataTable({
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  ajax: {
    url: 'almacenes/salidas_caja_detalle.ajax.php',
    dataSrc: ""
  },
  columnDefs: [
    {
      targets: 1,
      visible: false
    },
    {
      targets: 3,
      visible: true,
      render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 2, '')
    },
    {
      targets: 4,
      visible: false,
    }
```

I need to set the value of the targets: 1 to a variable to print it in other areas of the screen.

Comment: You need to add some more context. As it is, I don't think people can quite grasp what you're asking -- I certainly didn't.

Comment: You can take the [tour] and read [ask] for more guidance on how to write a more effective question.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. What _specifically_ do you mean by "_the value of the targets: 1_"? What data are you referring to? And what does "_other areas of the screen_" mean? Please be specific, and precise - and show us the relevant code and data, so we can easily recreate the _specific_ problem you are facing. You can take a look at [mre] for further guidance.